# passing variables through session - php

Tags: php, forms, session, variables, session-variables

I'm new to php and I'm trying to pass a the value of a submit button through a session.

my code so far looks like this:

main_page.php

```
     session_start();
     echo '<form method="post" action="details_page.php">';
 echo '<li><a href="ifconfig.php> <input type="submit" name=submit value='."$ip_address".' /></a></li>';
 echo '</form>';
     $value_to_pass = $_POST[submit];
 echo $value_to_pass;
     $_SESSION['value'] = $value_to_pass;

}
```

details_page.php

```
session_start();
    echo $value_to_pass = $_SESSION['value'];
    echo $value_to_pass;
```

I need it to print $value_to_pass in the details_page.php

Comment: Remove echo in `echo $value_to_pass = $_SESSION['value'];` Just leave the assignment. The rest of the code looks good.

Comment: This is not question related, rather your example related: `$value_to_pass = $_POST[submit];` should be: `$value_to_pass = $_POST['submit'];`

Answer (score 0):

This is highly confusing

```
 session_start();
 echo '<form method="post" action="details_page.php">';
 echo '<li><a href="ifconfig.php> <input type="submit" name=submit value='."$ip_address".' /></a></li>';
 echo '</form>';
 $value_to_pass = $_POST[submit];
 echo $value_to_pass;
 $_SESSION['value'] = $value_to_pass;
```

Consider changing it to this so that your POST code only gets executed when the form is actually submitted. Without this check your SESSION will be assigned a blank value when the form is not submitted which may be giving you odd results.

```
 session_start();
 echo '<form method="post" action="details_page.php">';
 echo '<li><a href="ifconfig.php> <input type="submit" name=submit value='."$ip_address".' /></a></li>';
 echo '</form>';

 // Note also you need single quotes in the $_POST array around 'submit'
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
   $value_to_pass = $_POST[submit];
   echo $value_to_pass;
   $_SESSION['value'] = $value_to_pass;
 }
```

And change details_page.php to

```
session_start();
// Do not echo this line, as you are echoing the assignment operation.
$value_to_pass = $_SESSION['value'];
var_dump($value_to_pass);
```

Answer (score 0):

first You change your below code

```
 echo '<form method="post" action="details_page.php">';
 echo '<li><a href="ifconfig.php> <input type="submit" name=submit value='."$ip_address".' /></a></li>';
 echo '</form>';
```

with the below

```
 echo '<form method="post" action="details_page.php">';
 echo '<input type="hidden" name="ip_address" id="ip_address" value="'.$ip_address.'">';
 echo '<li><a href="ifconfig.php> <input type="submit" name=submit /></a></li>';
 echo '</form>';
```

this is the best practice actually. I also followed this. So try to avoid passing values in "submit" button. pass it to "hidden" field.

and then get the value like below:-

```
 $value_to_pass = $_POST["ip_address"];
```

I think it will help You. Thanks.